# docker-compose.yml for DECIDIM don't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to create a docker image of DECIDIM with docker compose, but when I install it on docker, it gives me the following error:

> " Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP
> code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create
> failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec:
> "/code/vendor/hello-world.sh": stat /code/vendor/hello-world.sh: no
> such file or directory: unknown"

As you are the user of this application, I ask you directly, how to solve it.

https://github.com/decidim/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

PS: I'm running on windows AND only on windows. I can use powershell and WSL. I propose an issue on Github here: https://github.com/decidim/docker/issues/101

I try to use docker to creat a docker image with docker compose.But it's don't working.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://github.com/decidim/docker/issues/101#issuecomment-1418184735) of the dev is:

> The error you are facing is windows related.
> Try to run the following set of commands in a CMD terminal to configure git on your windows:
>
> ```bash
> git config --global core.fileMode false
> git config --global core.autocrlf true
> ```
>
> After that :
>
> ```bash
> git clone https://github.com/decidim/docker.git
> find ./docker -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix
> ```
>
> After that, everything should be okay, so you could run:
>
> ```bash
> cd docker 
> docker compose up
> ```

but `xargs` and `dos2unix` are no compatible with windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the commands, suggested by developer (https://github.com/decidim/docker/issues/101#issuecomment-1418184735), in Git Bash. It's usually installed along with Git for Windows. Then the commands should run fine:

```bash
git config --global core.fileMode false
git config --global core.autocrlf true

git clone https://github.com/decidim/docker.git
find ./docker -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix
```